# How can I overlay shapes and align text to its center in CSS?

Tags: html, css

```css
.grcircle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.recircle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.orcircle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.yecircle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.blcircle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.prcircle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: purple;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bar {
  height: 40px;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.grcircle,
text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grcircle"></div><text>hhi</text>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="recircle"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="orcircle"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="yecircle"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="blcircle"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="prcircle"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
```

Output:

[image: Screenshot]

I would like the little bars to be aligned with the centers of the circles, and have them overlayed by the circles, as if a connection.

Also, I would like to have the text on the right in line with the center of the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the other answer with `transform: translateX();` would be a quick fix, I'd suggest that you rethink the markup as a whole.

Something like below: (see live demo at this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/baadaa/pen/dyYJoPX))

```html
<div class="circle green">hhi</div>
<div class="circle red"></div>
<div class="circle orange"></div>
<div class="circle yellow"></div>
<div class="circle blue"></div>
<div class="circle purple"></div>
```

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  height: 20px;
}

.circle::before {
  content:"";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.circle::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 8px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 5px;
  background: grey;
  height: 40px;
}
.green::before {
  background-color: green;
}

.red::before {
  background-color: red;
}

.orange::before {
  background-color: orange;
}

.yellow::before {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue::before {
  background-color: blue;
}

.purple::before {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

What I did is:
1. Clean up HTML, so that unnecessary `div`s and `text` elements are eliminated
1. Reuse CSS classes, so that repetitive style declarations are consolidated
1. Use `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements for circle and bar connector styling.

Comment: thanks - how to I align the text to be next to the centre of the circle?

Comment: I’ve added a couple lines to `.circle` as below: `display: flex; align-items: center;`. Check the CodePen link again.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer  transform: translateX(); or Y.
I don't think my solution is the best, but it **works**

```
.bar {
    height: 40px;
    width: 5px;
    transform: translateX(7px);
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a highly responsive approach.

**OPTIONAL**

I would also propose the refactor of the `CSS` and also rather use `CSS3` attributes for `background`.

```css
.grid {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 20px auto;
}

.circle {
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.gr {
 background: green;
}

.re {
 background: red;
}

.or {
 background: orange;
}

.ye {
 background: yellow;
}

.bl {
 background: blue;
}

.pr {
 background: purple;
}

.bar {
 height: 40px;
 width: 5px;
 background: grey;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

 <div class="gr circle"></div><text>hhi</text>

 <div class="bar"></div><text></text>
 <div class="re circle"></div><text></text>
 <div class="bar"></div><text></text>
 <div class="or circle"></div><text></text>
 <div class="bar"></div><text></text>
 <div class="ye circle"></div><text></text>
 <div class="bar"></div><text></text>
 <div class="bl circle"></div><text></text>
 <div class="bar"></div><text></text>
 <div class="pr circle"></div><text></text>
 <div class="bar"></div><text></text>

</div>
```